# Play framework runs previous compiled code

Tags: scala, compilation, playframework-2.0

I'm having a problem with play framework: when I compile after modifying a single file and run it, it often runs the old compiled code. Seems to be using something like an internal cache.

system:
play 2.2.1 built with Scala 2.10.2 (running Java 1.7.0_25)

issue:
After recompiling the project and refreshing browser's view it is often still executed the previous code.

fix:
*clean compile* will fix it, by the way it's quite time consuming.

Thank you,
Pietro

Comment: Are you running it in `play run` mode?

Comment: no, I usually do some new work and then I stop the server, type "compile", "run" and then I push F5 in the browser.

Comment: of course, with "~run" it works

Comment: Then what is the question?

Answer (score 2):

Well this is because you are not running it in [development](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.2/PlayConsole) mode i.e. `play run`.

In this mode, the server will be launched with the auto-reload feature enabled, meaning that for each request Play will check your project and recompile required sources. If needed the application will restart automatically.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I'm afraid I've written something wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I'm used to type "enter" while writing. Anyway, if I stop the server, type "compile" and then "run" and then refresh the page I usually got the new code executed. Now it works randomly and requires often a "clean compile" before.

Comment: Please help me understand the question. So basically under the `run` mode, sometimes the browser still shows the old code even though the new code got updated?

Comment: Is that. And with "code" I mean Scala code (nothing that should be kept by the browser itself I think). This is since I switched to Play 2.2.1

Comment: Hmm one small thing (I had faced it once). Are you saving the scala file? SOmetimes we forget to save and then it doesnt work as expected.

Comment: Good point, I've made such mistakes :) but this time I'm sure it's not related to sources not saved.

Comment: @pietro909 Hmm then you should probably submit it as a bug then,

Comment: Submitted. Thank you for the discussion, your answer was indeed easy and precise but my reputation points don't allow me to upvote it.

Comment: @pietro909 Now you can :). Thanks.